# Augmented Reality Software/API

Tags: android, ios, api

Does anybody know what Caterpillar uses for their augmented reality software?
An example is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGtCQWROytw

If not, I am looking for augmented reality API that can be used with iOS and Android.  The API must be able to support 3D objects.  Like caterpillar does, I am looking to capture vehicles and display information over them.